# Can we execute list command or stored procedure inside a UDF or UDTF in snowflake?

Tags: stored-procedures, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Problem statement: we want to restrict the direct access to all the external STAGES to all the USER'S or DEVELOPER'S. We wanted these STAGES to be accessed through stored procedure or table UDF using LIST command.

We have following two working solutions :

**Solution 1**

1. Write a stored procedure and return a list command result set as single array or varchar with column delimiter (i.e. | ) and record delimiter (i.e. new line character)
2. Run view after calling above stored procedure using RESULT_SCAN(), LAST_QUERY_ID() and LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE() functions to show the result as flattened row level output similar to original LIST command.

**LIMITATIONS**

1. As the view is using LAST_QUERY_ID and RESULT_SCAN functions its mandatory to call the SP before the select on view every time otherwise select on view will fail.

**Solution 2**

1. Write a stored procedure and create volatile table inside it to store the list command result.
2. Run the select query on the volatile table created from the above stored procedure.

Both above solutions are working fine for us but with stored procedure approach the result can't be seen as tabular format with a single call to the stored procedure. As snowflake doesn't supports PL/SQL function like "dbms_output.put_line()" .

It's always a 2-step solution.

1. Call stored procedure
2. View result from that stored procedure output using RESULT_SCAN(), LAST_QUERY_ID() functions or creating table inside the stored procedure and run query on the created table after stored procedure execution is complete.

**Expected solution**

1. We want to view the output of a stored procedure or UDF in a single call with similar representation like any other query output in Snowflake Web UI worksheets.
2. We want to know if there is any possibility to use LIST command in snowflake UDF or UDTF any LANGUAGE like SQL or JAVASCRIPT will work for us.
3. Or else if we can call a stored procedure (i.e. explained in above two solutions) inside a UDF this will also suffice our need.

Please let us know if there is any possible solution for the any of the above expected output.

Answer (score 1):

I did not completely understand the requirement, but are you trying to do something like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LIST_EXTERNAL_STAGE(stage_name varchar)
RETURNS VARIANT
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    var return_stage_rows = []; 
    var snowstmt = snowflake.createStatement({
        sqlText: 'LIST '+ STAGE_NAME
    });
    
    var query_result = snowstmt.execute();
    var end_of_table = snowstmt.getRowCount();
     var counter = 0;
     
  while (counter <= end_of_table) {
    query_result.next();
    return_stage_rows.push(query_result.getColumnValue(1),query_result.getColumnValue(2),query_result.getColumnValue(3),query_result.getColumnValue(4))
    counter += 1;
    }
    
    return return_stage_rows;
$$;

call LIST_EXTERNAL_STAGE('@EMPLOYEE_STAGE');
```

[image]

Comment: I have already implemented similar stored procedure solution. The problem with above stored procedure is it returns single output row and I need the stored procedure output as tabular format like any other select query will provide in the worksheet. So, if i can call above stored procedure inside a UDTF to get output return as tabular format.

Comment: Also we can parse above stored procedure output and flatten the output as tabular multi column and multi row output. But this requires me to call a view or SQL query after running stored procedure. So, I don’t want this 2 step solution. I am looking for a way to get tabular output in single call to stored procedure or UDTF.

Comment: Right now you can't return a table from a stored procedure in Snowflake. UDFs and UDTFs do not have the snowflake API, so you cannot run a LIST command there. Until that changes you'll have to continue doing something along the lines of what you're doing.

Comment: @GregPavlik - Thanks for this information. Now i am at least sure that this isn't possible as of now. I will go ahead with any of the two solutions i have mentioned in above description.